# AngularJS How to get additional routes parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

Is there a way to add extra parameters to the $routeProvider and retrieve this parameters in a directive? I need this because the variable is page specific.

I would like to add a parameter pageName to the routeprovider like so:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/home',
        {
            controller: 'homeController',
            templateUrl: '_templates/home.html',
            pageName: 'home'
        })
```

And use this extra parameter in a directive like so

```
directives.dirPagename = ['$route', '$routeParams', function($route, $routeParams) {
    return {
        restrict: 'ECA',
        template: 'test',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log($route);
            console.log($routeParams);
        }
    }
 }]
```

When I log $route and inspect this inside google webdeveloper tools the pageName parameter is a few layers deep.

```
Object {routes: Object, reload: function}
    current: D
       $$route: Object
            controller: "homeController"
            **pageName: "home"**
```

Is there a way to directly get this variable or is this totally the wrong way to go?

UPDATE:

You can get the variables in routing with
var pageName = $route.routes[$location.$$path].pageName;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the information in $route.routes[uri].

I share with you my viewRouter service as an exemple:

```
var uaViewRouter = angular.module('ua.ViewRouter', []);

uaViewRouter.service('uaViewProvider', function($route, $location, uaContext){
    this.redirectToView = function(viewName){
        url = undefined;
        for(var route in $route.routes){
            if ($route.routes[route].view == viewName){
                url = route;
            }
        }
        if(url == undefined){
            throw("uaViewProvider: Undefined view " + viewName);
        }
        if($route.routes[url].enrichment == true){
            url = url.replace(":operatorId", uaContext.operator.get().id);
            url = url.replace(":productId", uaContext.product.get().id);
        }
        $location.path(url);
    };
});

uaViewRouter.run(function($rootScope, uaViewProvider) {
    $rootScope.uaViewProvider = {};
    $rootScope.uaViewProvider.redirectToView = function(viewName) {
        uaViewProvider.redirectToView(viewName);
    };
});
```

Exemple of route declaration:

```
uaApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'app/login/login.tpl.html',
            loginRequired: false,
            view: 'login'
        }).
...
```

You can use it in your controller or service by calling:

```
uaViewProvider.redirectToView('login');
```

Or in the template:

```
<a href="" ng-click="uaViewProvider.redirectToView('login')">Click to login</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm getting the right var with 
var pageName = $route.routes[$location.$$path].pageName;